# How to split a photo into circles in PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, photo-editing

Hy there

I have an idea that can be originated to spitting a photograph into separate pieces and hang on the wall (see picture attached). However I would like to divide the picture into smaller-bigger circles (providing this 'bubbly' effect on the wall) but still be able to see the photograph as one picture.

Additionally I would like to print the photograph on paper or canvas and place on wooden or plastic rims/frames that have 4-5cm depth so if we look at the wall from aside or from an angle the circles have some depth. Each circle frame would be covered by the pictures so every circle cut of the photo needs an extra 5cm radius. The extra 5cm radius would be the duplication of the outer 5cm of picture cuts.
As my highly sophisticated design plan ( :D) demonstrates on the last picture, the area between the blue and yellow circle needs to be duplicated in order to cover the round frames' edge.

HOW to do the design (in PS) in order to print the desired circles?!

Thank you 
[image: picture sliced in rectangles]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you locate the image you want to use for the wall decoration, print it in the size you want to use. For minimizing expense you can print portions of the image on different pieces.
*TIP: For added variety, solid colour or patterned disks can be made part of the grouping as well as circular graphic or typographic pieces.*

Decide the position and size of the circles you wish to use and cut them out. Smaller circles can fill in among larger surrounding ones.

If you want to hang the disks so that they appear as if looking through round windows half-an-inch apart, cut each of the circles 1/4" smaller than the circles you used to divide the whole image.
*(That's the arrangement of the image you provided of the dessert scene above of the thirsty giraffes.)* The shapes are as far apart as the missing part of the image.
To get a similar effect with your disks, cut the images smaller by half the amount of the distance you want to hang the image disks apart.
For example: If you want to hang the disks with one inch separating them, trim half-an-inch from the diameter of each of the image disks you wish to use.

If you want to hang the disks in the final arrangement so that they actually touch each other to create the desired effect, cut the circles carefully in full size so the circles just touch.

Mount the circular pieces on circular blocks (foam) as thick as you want to match the circumference of the image circles. Before you do, paint the edges of the circular image mounts matte black so there will be minimal issues with different colour and lighting schemes.

Comment: TIP: If you mount anything on styrofoam, mount the same material using the same method on the back (using scraps) to minimize the tendency to warp as environmental conditions such as temperature, pressure, and humidity change.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to GDSE!

For what you need, I would suggest using [masks](https://designshack.net/articles/graphics/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-masking-in-photoshop/)

In order to do this, the workflow that I would suggest is;

Open your file (good start) ;)

Make a new layer (bottom right of the layer panel)

Hit 'U' to access the shape tool - you'll want to select the ellipse tool as below;

[image: Ellipse Tool]

Holding SHIFT and dragging your cursor will enable you to make a circle shape. The properties for this circle can be changed in the properties panel, so don't worry if you don't get the right size first time.

[image: Properties Panel]

So the bit to consider here is the W and H properties, you'll want to change them to make sure that they are the size that you need. (Click the link icon between the pair so that you only have to type the change once). The colour of the circle won't matter as we will be simply using it to make a selection.

So you've already established that you want an extra 5cm on the radius of the circle to make sure that you can cover the sides of the print. I would also suggest adding approx. 3mm [bleed](http://www.serviceprinters.com/help/bleed-in-printing.html) to that there are no white patches.

Now, you should have an Ellipse 1 layer and it should be at the dimensions that you have figured out. If you CTRL/CMD + right click on the thumbnail for this layer, it will give you a selection of your ellipse (there'll be marching ants). When this happens, select your background layer in the layers panel and then simply click the mask button (rectangular icon with a circle inside - to the right of fX) at the bottom of the layers panel.

If you turn off your ellipse layer, you should be left with the circular shape of your background image.

Now, right click (or alt + drag) to duplicate that background layer, right click on the mask to delete it and make your next ellipse to start the process again.

Once you have completed this process as many times as you need you should be in a position to start saving out the PDFs of the appropriate layers. Remember to make sure your document is set up as CMYK and about 300ppi.

*Also just to make clear, this is how to achieve circles like you asked but with print you might as well print the rectangular/square shape and the physically trim the excess once you've managed to get the kind of frame/mount that you want*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to use stretched canvas you need to account for bleed around each shape which means if you have shapes touching each other, the bleed will overlap. You may be able to do this in photoshop, but I would bring the image into Illustrator, setup the arrangement of the shapes, create an offset of the path that matches what the canvas stretcher needs, then create artboards around each bleed (offset).  Then output the artboards as individual print ready files and have them printed like that.  We create multi-panel murals for tradeshow exhibit displays and wrap printed vinyl around the edges of the substrate to prevent the edge of the substrate from being seen.  Works great for us.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to end up with stretched canvas, I think you would have to get/make the circular frames.

Then have these printed on canvas and trim them. Or get prints made and trim them, then mount.

To have them printed, you'd need to place the round image files into a rectangular shape. Then trim.

Imagekind.com used to be pretty good at unusual requests like this. You might contact them before sending anything.